# surf plot: wrongly connected mesh vertices

Tags: pgfplots

I have troubles with resembling a matlab `surface` plot in pgfplots.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \tikz{
        \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]%
            \addplot3 [
            surf,
            shader=flat,
            z buffer=sort,
            mesh/cols=50,
            mesh/rows=50,
            point meta=\thisrow{c},
            draw=none,
            domain=0:10
            ]
            table[col sep=comma] {data.dat};
        \end{axis}
    }
\end{document}
```

with the test data being uploaded here: https://gist.github.com/bonanza123/e9a696bc0e9c727180d34046d9abbc90

The code above gives me this output:
[image: pgfplots/surf]

To me, it looks like the vertices in the mesh vertices are not connected correctly. But how to fix that?

While I want something like this:
[image: matlab]

---

The matlab plot and the data linked above is generated as per:

```
surface(X,Y,Z,'EdgeColor','interp','FaceColor','interp');
data = struct2table( struct( 'x', X, 'y', Y, 'c', Z ) );
writetable( data, 'data.dat' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the `nan`s which require: `unbounded coords=jump`.